How to confirm ready state for an external USB disk before attempting other actions
[start of edit 1]
Before I plug in my external USB backup drive, my computer is fully booted-up, and I am in my session as root.  Because of its location, my USB cord is already plugged in, but I manually plug in my power cord for the drive when I need it.
[end of edit 1]
I have routines for mounting the multiple partitions found on an external USB3 MyBook hard drive.
I have not had any issues in having the partitions mount because after plugging in my USB drive, I hold my hand on the drive to "feel" when the Linux initiation routines are done by choosing when I no longer sense the vibration from the writing head's movement.
Is there a command line utility which I can call upon, from a script, that I could add to my mounting script, such that I wouldn't have to feel the ready state, but instead have Linux probe/wait/signalGO when the drive is finally ready (after the initial fsck's, etc.) so that it knows when to wait/proceed with the disk-related scripts?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
